# aws sesv2 , is not working in the aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

The aws CLI documentation shows that we can create and search suppression details using sesv2 but when I try to use the CLI command in my mac its returning error that"Invalid choice". My awscli version is 1.16.209. The endpoint is working in the boto3 but not in the awscli

```
aws-cli/1.16.209 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.12.172
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sesv2/index.html#cli-aws-sesv2

is the sesv2 option working for anyone? or Am i using the wrong awscli version?

Comment: What is the specific command you are trying to use? I ran `aws sesv2 list-configuration-sets` and it worked fine. My version is `aws-cli/1.16.290 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.13.26`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across same issue today. You might be using aws version 1. This is what I suggest.

1. Upgrade/install aws version 2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html)
2. Run the ses2 commands now: aws2 sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations --reason BOUNCE